# Pandas DataFrame, how to calculate a new column element based on multiple rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, number-crunching

I am currently trying to implement a statistical test for a specific row based on the content of different rows. Given the dataframe in the following image:

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Ml0.png)
I would like to create a new column based on a function that takes into account all the columns of the dataframe that has the same string in column "Template".

For example, in this case there are 2 rows with Template "[Are|Off]", and for each one of those rows I would need to create an element in a new column based on "Clicks", "Impressions" and "Conversions" of both rows.

How would you best approach this problem?

PS: I apologise in advance for the way I am describing the problem, as you might have notices I am not a professional codes :D But I would really appreciate your help!

Here the formula with which I solved this in excel:

[Excel Chi Squared test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5XJA.png)

Comment: What are you desired output of the new column? You're only saying 'based' on, is that the sum of the other columns or what?

Comment: First u need to gropby using Template and then do mathematical part on coloumns and other coloumn ..u can use map/vectorize for this

Comment: @HugoHonorem the output of the new column is a chi squared test, I added an example of how I deal with this in excel, maybe it makes it more clear!

Comment: @DarkMatter I tried this solution with groupby or pivoting, but i am stuck in the second part since I do not only need the sum or the 22 rows. Maybe the excel solution I pasted might help you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be overly general but I would use some sort of function map if different things should be done depending on the template name:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import collections

n = 5
template_column = list(['are|off', 'are|off', 'comp', 'comp', 'comp|city'])
n = len(template_column)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((n, 3)), index=range(n), columns=['Clicks', 'Impressions', 'Conversions'])
df['template'] = template_column

# Use a defaultdict so that you can define a default value if a template is
# note defined
function_map = collections.defaultdict(lambda: lambda df: np.nan)

# Now define functions to compute what the new columns should do depending on
# the template.
function_map.update({
    'are|off': lambda df: df.sum().sum(),
    'comp': lambda df: df.mean().mean(),
    'something else': lambda df: df.mean().max()
})

# The lambda functions are just placeholders.  You could do whatever you want in these functions... for example:

def do_special_stuff(df):
    """Do something that uses rows and columns... 
    you could also do looping or whatever you want as long 
    as the result is a scalar, or a sequence with the same 
    number of columns as the original template DataFrame
    """
    crazy_stuff = np.prod(np.sum(df.values,axis=1)[:,None] + 2*df.values, axis=1)
    return crazy_stuff

function_map['comp'] = do_special_stuff

def wrap(f):
    """Wrap a function so that it returns an updated dataframe"""

    def wrapped(df):
        df = df.copy()
        new_column_data = f(df.drop('template', axis=1))
        df['new_column'] = new_column_data
        return df

    return wrapped

# wrap all the functions so that each template has a function defined that does
# the correct thing
series_function_map = {k: wrap(function_map[k]) for k in df['template'].unique()}

# throw everything back together
new_df = pd.concat([series_function_map[label](group)
                    for label, group in df.groupby('template')],
                   ignore_index=True)

# print your shiny new dataframe
print(new_df)
```

The result is then something like:

```
     Clicks  Impressions  Conversions   template  new_column
0  0.959765     0.111648     0.769329    are|off    4.030594
1  0.809917     0.696348     0.683587    are|off    4.030594
2  0.265642     0.656780     0.182373       comp    0.502015
3  0.753788     0.175305     0.978205       comp    0.502015
4  0.269434     0.966951     0.478056  comp|city         NaN
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Davis, from what I understand, this solution relies on aggregated data for each template, which is different from the way I need to calculate my output. The function I need to use should work as follows: Let's suppose I have Template A in 2 rows (A.1 and A.2), I would need to fill the new column both on the individual numbers inserted in each one of the 2 rows (A.1 and A.2), and also on the sum of them (A.1 + A.2). Please feel free to let me know if is not clear so I can improve my description :)

Comment: @RobertoBertinetti, I added a `do_special_stuff(df)` function to demonstrate that you don't have to use a complete aggregate function like in the lambdas above it.  This way you have pretty much total freedom.

Comment: thanks again for the explanation and clarification, will try this out and let you know!

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after groupby u need to apply this formula ..so you can do this in pandas also ...

```
import numpy as np
t = df.groupby("Template") # this is for groupby
def calculater(b5,b6,c5,c6):
    return b5/(b5+b6)*((c5+c6))
t['result'] = np.vectorize(calculater)(df["b5"],df["b6"],df["c5"],df["c6"])
```

here b5,b6 .. are column names of the cells shown in image

This should work for you or may need to do some minor changes in maths there

Comment: The B5, b6 in excel are actually not column names, but the cells. Does that make sense anyway?

Comment: Anyway they should have some column names rite ?? ... :) ....use those column names

Comment: And I edited answer according to your suggetions ...thanx

Comment: In the function you suggested though, there are 4 entries, while I have only 2 columns: B and C (from which I take elements from 2 rows: 5 and 6). So I cannot apply directly the funciton